Eclipse RCP Help in Browser
I have an RCP application that I have attached my help plugin to. Help opens when I click Open Help, then a new window opens with the help. Is there a way to make my help plugin open in a browser window?
My help plugin.xml code:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.toc">
         <toc file="toc_Concepts.xml" />
         <toc file="toc_Ref.xml" />
         <toc file="toc_Tasks.xml" />
      <toc
            file="toc.xml">
      </toc>
      <toc
            file="testToc.xml"
            primary="true">
      </toc>
   </extension>
      <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
         <command
               commandId="org.eclipse.ui.help.displayHelp"
               label="Open Help"
               tooltip="Open the Eclipse Help System">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>


You can choose that in the preferences Help > Content. For your RCP application, you can set the default in your plugin_customization.ini file.

If I create an Eclipse Product will it also open in a browser?

For a product, you can specify the default in your plugin_customization.ini file which can be changed by the user in the preferences Help > Content. For a plugin, you do not want to change the behavior of the general commands and might want implement your own commands.

Where can i find plugin_customization.ini file? And could you give me an example of writing code inside it?

See Eclipse Help and for example e.g. how the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers does it or how I do it. See also the link in my first comment how to get the values for your plugin_customization.ini.

I'm new to Eclipse so I'm not quite sure why I need this or how to use it.

A product mostly has a customization plugin which contains the splash screen, plugin_customization.ini, etc. Beside the New Plug-in dialog which provides a couple of templates (especially, when on the second page This plug-in will make contributions to the UI is selected) and the Eclipse help there a couple of tutorials at vogella.com which also explain the plugin_customization.ini.
